# Comparing two sentences and merge while removing duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I plan on creating a remarks column within my sheet, and I want it to be such that whenever I update one side or the other, it will merge the remark and remove any duplicates within it.

Would appreciate if anyone has any inputs on this.

Example:
Remarks in the column of one google sheet:
-Friendly -Fun

Remarks in the other column of another google sheet :
-Friendly -Cheerful

So my google script will get the string in both columns, I would like to make the end result of the string to be :
-Friendly -Cheerful -Fun

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I plan on creating a remarks column within my sheet, and I want it to be such that whenever I update one side or the other, it will merge the remark and remove any duplicates within it.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect? And also, when you are using a script, can you provide your script and the detail of the issue of your script?

Comment: you can find more inputs if you can provide a sample of your data or table here

Comment: @Tanaike I have added some edits, I can't seem to make a proper table, but I hope it is understandable

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Example: Remarks on one end : | Remarks | | -------- | | -Friendly - Nice|`, `Remarks on the other end : | Remarks | | -------- | | -Friendly - Fun|`, `End results : | Remarks | | -------- | | -Friendly - Nice -Fun|`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Ivan, it would be much more efficient and effective, as well as garner more engagement from the volunteer contributors here, if you would share a link to a sample spreadsheet with enough realistic data to illustrate the end goal. Manually enter the results where you would like to see them. And be sure to set the link's permissions (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that people can actually access the sheet, test, and leave any working solutions for you in the sheet.

Comment: @ErikTyler See [Why should I include screenshots instead of a Google sheets link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/)

Comment: @Ivan See [tables format rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support). Even if you can't properly add formatting, the community can later format it for you.

Comment: @ErikTyler Thank you for reading the post. Feel free to add a answer in my meta post. But, I'm of the opinion that you misunderstood Stackoverflow's goal, which is not exactly to help people, but to create a comprehensive question/answer site. The idea is to build a good quality repo of Q/As that'll help the entire community - not just OP. [Do read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/)

Comment: @TheMaster, not to be contrary, but you are strongly stating a stance; and so the choices are to accept it (or to appear to) or to advocate for my own take on things. And as I am the only one responsible for how I use my time, including donating it to this forum, I'm inclined toward the latter. The fact is that I myself will not answer most posts at all unless there is readily available data already entered into a sheet. So my answers would be absent from "a comprehensive Q/A site" if not for the sharing of sheets, which also defeats the purpose (at least where my involvement is concerned).

Comment: @TheMaster, if it causes you to feel any better, I'm happy to qualify future requests for shared sheets with the addition of something to the effect of "If you would like MY help on this issue, please share a link to a spreadsheet..."

Comment: @ErikTyler  You state the issues with images. But how about tables. It's a solid middle ground. Copy pasting a table doesn't seem to be much work and I know sheets readily accepts it.  In any case, it's just my stance and not a rule. I'm sure SO/meta users would agree with the concept of "self contained" question, but it's not a rule and rules would default to what majority of users who are active in that tag determine.

Comment: @ErikTyler SO repository would be better with tables. But, It would make my privacy consciousness feel better if you said "Provide a sheet link with a "throwaway" account".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238292/discussion-between-erik-tyler-and-themaster).

Answer (score 1):

[image: FilterUnique]

Can you try like this to what I understand and see attached image as will

```
=Unique(Transpose(Split(TEXTJOIN(" ",True,B2,D2),"-",True)),False,False)
```